# Get Python turtle to face in direction of line being plotted

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to get the turtle shape to follow the direction of a line.

I have a simple parabola and I want the turtle shape to follow the direction of the line - when the graph goes up, the turtle faces up and when the graph comes down, the turtle faces down.
I am using `goto()` for the position of the turtle and `x=x+1` for the x position on the graph:

```
t.goto(x,y)
t.right(??) - this?
t.left(??) - this?
t.setheading(??) or this?
```

What is the best method to achieve this?  When I have tried using `t.right()` in a `while` loop (I am looping until x is complete), the turtle continues to spin in a circle as it moves, which is **not** what I want.

---

Still not getting this.  I added the extra code that was suggested - here is the EDIT and the full code for what I am trying to achieve...

I am using the physics formula for trajectory (I used this so I know my values outputted are correct).
http://www.softschools.com/formulas/physics/trajectory_formula/162/

```
import math
import turtle
import time
w=turtle.Turtle()


i=0
angle=66.4
velocity=45.0
g=9.8

t=math.tan(math.radians(angle))
c=math.cos(math.radians(angle))

turtle.delay(9)

w.shape("turtle")
w.setheading(90)

while i < 150:
    start = i * t
    middle = g*(i**2)
    bottom =(2*(velocity**2)*c**2)
    total = start-middle/bottom
    print(total)

    w.setheading(turtle.towards(i,total))
    w.goto(i,total)

    i=i+1

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at the code I edited for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The orientation of the turtle can be determined from the derivative of your function at the current position.

If you have the function as a sympy function, you can ask Python to do the differentiation. Or you could just do it on your own. If your function is

```
y = x^2
```

, then the derivative is

```
dy = 2 * x
```

Given that derivative at the current position, its arc tangent gives you the turtle's heading:

```
t.setheading(math.atan(dy))
```

Make sure that the angle mode of the turtle is set to radians or convert them to degrees

```
t.setheading(math.degrees(math.atan(dy)))
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am still trying to understand that if I put in a number, such at t.right(90), it will continue to spin in a circle as it makes it way through the parabola.

Comment: Because `t.right(90)` means: Make a 90° right turn from your current orientation. And multiple right turns will eventually make a circle.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @NicoSchertler that the arc tangent of the derivative is the way to go mathematically.  But if it's just for good visuals, there's a simpler way.  We can combine turtle's `setheading()` and `towards()` methods, constantly setting the turtle's heading towards the next position just before we go there:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

turtle = Turtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-20, -400)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.showturtle()

for x in range(-20, 20):

    y = -x ** 2

    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x, y))
    turtle.goto(x, y)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]